# Pushing a local vagrant server to Ocean Digital

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, digital-ocean

I'm been working on a vagrant larval server, which I get the VagrantFile from [here](https://github.com/bryannielsen/Laravel4-Vagrant). I'm just curious as to how I would push this server to a digital ocean droplet with all the server settings kept the same (same php mods installed, same database credentials, etc).

Is it even possible to do this? Or would I have to manually install everything on a digital ocean droplet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [provisioning](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html) to setup server settings including packages installing, passwords setting, etc (this **is** the Vagrant-way). After this, you may use [vagrant-digitalocean](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean) project to set Digital Ocean as Vagrant provider. Simply update [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/bryannielsen/Laravel4-Vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile) with settings required by "vagrant-digitalocean". This probably should do the trick.

Comment: Just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305240/setting-up-a-vagrant-with-a-digitalocean-image), I still have no idea how exactly to test a local environment and then deploy it to a droplet in a repeatable way. Anyone? Please?